# How exactly does Java Scanner parse double?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, locale

I'm using a Windows 7 machine whose "Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region" is "Denmark"

According to the documentation for [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the Locale.getDefault() method;

But when I run the code:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
Scanner sc = new Scanner("1.0");
sc.nextDouble();
```

It outputs "en_US" and then throws a java.util.InputMismatchException at sc.nextDouble() .
It works when the scanner is initialized with "1,0"

However, if I explicitly set the Locale:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
Scanner sc = new Scanner("1.0");
sc.nextDouble();
```

It outputs "en_US" and then parses the double just fine. Am I missing something, or is the documentation for Scanner wrong?

**Edit** Following the suggestion of @Perception, I looked at sc.locale() in the first example. It prints "da_DK". So why is it not "en_US", when that is what is being returned by the Locale.getDefault() method?

Comment: Seems like your computer thinks it's in France or French Canada...

Comment: Why would it print out `en_US` then? But @AndrewMao must be right, it works for me.

Comment: What part of the documentation is not understandable?

Comment: What does `sc.locale()` print for you, in your first example?

Comment: @Perception It prints "da_DK" - but why does it do that? Does the documentation state that it should take Locale from Locale.getDefault()?

Comment: @PaulVargas The specific thing I don't understand is that I interpret the documentation to state that Scanner takes it Locale from Locale.getDefault(), but apparently it does not, the Scanner's initial locale is "da_DK".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different [Locale categories](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.Category.html), one for display and one for format. The scanner uses `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` but if you call `Locale.getDefault()` you get the locale for display. The `setLocale(Locale)` method sets both.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find this stated in any documentation (for Scanner).

Comment: You're wright, the official [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers) is misleading. It is even stated that `A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the Locale.getDefault() method`.

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers) was corrected in Java 8.